# android activity call requestWindowFeature first and show the title

Tags: android

My Activitys use a theme which set `android:windowNoTitle = true`.But I have to show the title in some activities. I want show the title in my activity by call `requestWindowFeature()`, but it's not work! Any help would be great.

Thanks.

ps:
My activitys hava to be switched between two themes.The homeActivty use the actionbar and others no title.These activtys are use the same themes.So when before use requestWindowFeature() it's been hiding, and i just want show it now.

Here is my codes:
Defined theme:

```
    <!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/activityAnimation</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!-- <item name="android:background">@color/background_holo_light</item> -->
</style>
```

And use the theme in application:

```
    <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Get and change the theme if necessary:

```
int mThemeId = mSettingPreferences.getInt(MySettings.THEME_ID, -1);
    if (-1 != mThemeId) {
        this.setTheme(mThemeId);
    }
    // do something to show the title
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use this method before your **setContentView** method...

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

**OR**

And yes you can add theme in Manifest file in which Activity you don't want to Title..Then use this..

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activity name"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" 
        android:screenOrientation="potrait" >
    </activity>
```

first change this:

```
if (mThemeId != -1) {
    this.setTheme(mThemeId);
}
```

and after that you can use

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
```

Comment: @Karain means just want to show title in some activities and in some activies not using requestWindowFeature()??

Comment: @Piyush Gupta Yes, that's what my means.

Comment: but this method applicable for your requirement....And you can also use custom theme of your own making

Comment: My activitys hava to be switched between two themes.The homeActivty use the actionbar and others no title.These activtys are use the same themes.So when before use requestWindowFeature() it's been hiding, and i just want show it now.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
```

You don't need to apply any **Theme** if you use this.

Comment: My activitys hava to be switched between two themes.The homeActivty use the actionbar and others no title.These activtys are use the same themes.So when before use requestWindowFeature() it's been hiding, and i just want show it now.

Comment: dude how many times i told you just use this code before setcontentview and ur issue is solved.dont use anything else like theme to set anything

Comment: Yes, i know how to solve this issue, but i also want to know how to solve this issue after call requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Answer (score 0):

```
       <activity
            android:name=".HistoryImage"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HistoryVideo"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HistoryVideo_2"
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" 
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait" >
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you must call requestWindowFeature(); before setContentView()
```

Answer (score 0):

The activities in which you don't want to show the title bar. just do this to hide the title bar. befor setcontentView `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_page);
```