# RequestFeature Issue ...in onNewIntent()

Tags: android

I tried adding before and after setContent method but facing the issue still  "    android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
"

```
 public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
        final boolean customTitleSupported =
                requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        super.onNewIntent(intent);

        session = new SessionManagement(getApplicationContext());
        if(customTitleSupported){
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,R.layout.item);
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.itemlist);
        setIntent(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE)` before you call `setContentView()`. A good place would be right *before* `super.onCreate()` in you `onCreate` method in your `Activity`.

Comment: I am doing the same..,actually this is my OnNewIntent() ,so i have super.onNewIntent()

Comment: I'm sorry, it should be added before any lay-out is rendered, which means, it has to be before `super.onCreate()`. See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18821563

Comment: The same? You are talking about `onNewIntent()`. Are you sure `requestWindowFeature()` is also called before `super.onCreate()` in `onCreate()`?